# Modifying stack in another class

Tags: java, stack

Trying to get my head around get/set methods, specifically how to modify a stack held by another class....

Class A has the following instance variable:

```
public class ClassA {
    private Stack<String> stack;
    public ClassA {
        stack = new Stack<String>();
    }
}
```

An object of type Class A is an instance variable in Class B:

```
public class Class B {
    private ClassA classa;
    public Class B(ClassA classa) {
        this.classa = classa;
    }
}
```

Class B needs to pop() and push() the stacks in Class A. Does Class A need to implement a get method like so:

```
public Stack<String> getStack() {
    return stack;   
}
```

and then Stack B has the following method:

```
public void Pop(){
    try {
        String a = classa.getStack().pop();
    }
    catch (EmptyStackException e) {
    }  
}
```

Or, does ClassA need to implement a set method? e.g.

```
public void popStack() {
    stack.pop();    
}
```

Resulting in the following in Class B.....

```
public void Pop(){
    try {
        String a = classa.popStack();
    }
    catch (EmptyStackException e) {
    }  
}
```

When the stack variable is returned, I don't know if modifying it modifies the original held by Class A, or whether it returns a copy.....

Comment: notice that you have to return the String in `popStack()`, so do `public String popStack()` instead of `public void popStack()`

Comment: Ah yes, that is actually what I had in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Class A should provide method to `push` and `pop` stuff from its stack. Returning the whole stack with a `get` method is not very good; as a general rule, do not return stuff the user doesn't need.

**You should learn about encapsulation.** It is a very important concept of object-oriented programming and you won't be able to design quality applications without knowing about it.

Comment: @javapalava do not hesitate to accept the answer if it was useful. Also, read about encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, since your stack is being held by the class A, it is not a good practice to directly give the stack to the class B. Instead, you can implement methods in `class A` as you suggested to `pop` the stack and to `push` to the stack. This is an example where JAVA **encapsulation** is exhibited.

Always try to keep the underlying implementation hidden as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make A implement the same methods as in the Stack interface and just pass them on to its Stack member?

```
public String pop()
   {
       return stack.pop();
   }
public String push(String item)
   {
       return stack.push(item);
   }
```

it's better design than exposing the Stack object in A...